# Creating graphs for various observations(countries) within a new function but I receive an error could not find function "%>%<-"

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I want to plot graphs for each country within a function instead of creating a for loop or write the code multiple times for each country. So, I wrote the following function code.

```
country_plot <- function(i){
  suicide %>%
    filter(Country == i) %>% 
    plot = ggplot(suicide, aes(x=Age_group, fill = Gender, y=Value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + ggtitle(i) + ylab("Suicide Rates") + xlab("Age Groups") + theme_minimal()
    return(plot[[i]])
}

country_plot("Chad")
```

But I receive the following error even though the packages dplyr and Magrittr are installed.

```
Error in suicide %>% filter(Country == i) %>% plot = ggplot(suicide, aes(x = Age_group,  : 
  could not find function "%>%<-"
```

Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: You are piping the output of `filter` to an assignment, which is causing the error.

Comment: Try something like: `dat <- suicide %>% filter(Country == i); plot <- ggplot(dat, ...)`

Comment: If I remove the pipe, the output is null. Is there something else that might be incorrect? Thanks though

Comment: ... and use `return(plot)`.

Comment: That is a different problem. The output of `ggplot` is not a named list. So you cannot call it like `plot[[i]]`. That is why you are getting `NULL`.

Comment: Please share a sample data using `dput`.